# JFreeChart is not updating ChartPanel, after reading data from serial port

Tags: refresh, jfreechart, chartpanel

I am trying to read some data from serial port and display the same using JFreeChart and ChartPanel. 
After I click button 'Aquire' I get new set of data from serial port. For the first time when panel is getting displayed, the values read from serial port is displayed. After I click the button 'Aquire', the values are getting populated in variable 'dataset' but they are not getting refreshed on the graph. Where am I going wrong? please help. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseListener;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYLineAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.event.ChartChangeEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.event.ChartChangeListener;
import org.jfree.chart.panel.CrosshairOverlay;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.Crosshair;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge;

public class DisplayPanel extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    SimplePortComm spc;
    JFreeChart xylineChart;
    ChartPanel panel;
    XYSeriesCollection dataset;
    public static String sLLD;
    public static String sULD;

    Label lblTitle;
    Label lblMax, lblMin, lblULD, lblLLD;
    TextField txtMax, txtMin, txtULD, txtLLD;
    Label lblInrangeCount;
    TextField txtInrangeCount;
    Button bAquire, bSave, bLoad, bQuit;
    int i, nInRangeChannels;
    private Crosshair xCrosshair;
    private Crosshair yCrosshair;


    double dULD,dLLD;

    public DisplayPanel() {

        dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

        spc = new SimplePortComm();


        lblTitle = new Label("Data Aquisition System for MCA");
        lblTitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 20));

        lblMax = new Label("Max:");
        lblMin = new Label("Min:");
        lblULD = new Label("ULD:");
        lblLLD = new Label("LLD:");
        lblInrangeCount = new Label("Count in Range:");
        lblInrangeCount.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 20));

        txtMax = new TextField(10);
        txtMax.setEditable(false);
        txtMin = new TextField(10);
        txtMin.setEditable(false);
        txtULD = new TextField(10);
        txtULD.setText("240.0");
        txtLLD = new TextField(10);
        txtLLD.setText("20.0");
        txtInrangeCount = new TextField(10);
        txtInrangeCount.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 20));
        txtInrangeCount.setEditable(false);

        dULD = Double.parseDouble(txtULD.getText());
        dLLD = Double.parseDouble(txtLLD.getText());
        drawChart();

        bAquire = new Button("Aquire");      
        bAquire.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 60));
        bAquire.addActionListener(
          new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aquire) {
                //panel.setRefreshBuffer(true); 
                System.setSecurityManager(null);// with out this statement, set_ports() throws null pointer exception
                spc.set_ports(dULD, dLLD);
                dataset = SimplePortComm.dataset;

                panel.repaint();
                panel.updateUI();

                System.out.print("Button: Aquire");
            }
          }
        );

        bSave = new Button("Save");
        bSave.setPreferredSize(null);
        bSave.addActionListener(
          new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent save) {
                System.out.print("Button: Save");
            }
          }
        );

        bLoad = new Button("Load");
        bLoad.setPreferredSize(null);
        bLoad.addActionListener(
          new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent load) {
                System.out.print("Button: Load");
                sLLD = txtLLD.getText();
                sULD = txtULD.getText();

                txtInrangeCount.setText(Integer.toString(spc.getInRangeChannels()));                
            }
          }
        );

        bQuit = new Button("Quit");
        bQuit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        bQuit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent quit) {
                System.out.print("Button: Quit");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());     
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(lblTitle)
            .addComponent(panel)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(bAquire)   
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblMax)
                    .addComponent(lblMin))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(txtMax)
                    .addComponent(txtMin))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblULD)
                    .addComponent(lblLLD))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(txtULD)
                    .addComponent(txtLLD)))
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(lblInrangeCount)
            .addComponent(txtInrangeCount))
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(bSave)
            .addComponent(bLoad)
            .addComponent(bQuit))
      );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(lblTitle)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(bAquire))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblMax)
                        .addComponent(txtMax)
                        .addComponent(lblULD)
                        .addComponent(txtULD))                          
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblMin)
                        .addComponent(txtMin)
                        .addComponent(lblLLD)
                        .addComponent(txtLLD))))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblInrangeCount)
                    .addComponent(txtInrangeCount))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(bSave)
                    .addComponent(bLoad)
                    .addComponent(bQuit))
            );

        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);     
        getContentPane().setEnabled(true);
        getContentPane().setSize(1500, 1500);


    }
    public void drawChart()
    {
        System.setSecurityManager(null);// with out this statement, set_ports() throws null pointer exception
        spc.set_ports(dULD, dLLD);
        dataset = SimplePortComm.dataset;

        xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                 "Data Aquired" ,
                 "Time" ,
                 "Amplitude" ,
                 dataset ,
                 PlotOrientation.VERTICAL ,
                 true , true , false);

        panel = new ChartPanel(xylineChart, 650, 450, 180, 180, 800, 600, false, true, false, false, false, false);
        //panel.setRefreshBuffer(true);

        CrosshairOverlay crosshairOverlay = new CrosshairOverlay();
        this.xCrosshair = new Crosshair(Double.NaN, Color.BLACK, 
                new BasicStroke(0f));
        this.xCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
        this.yCrosshair = new Crosshair(Double.NaN, Color.BLACK, 
                new BasicStroke(0f));
        this.yCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
        crosshairOverlay.addDomainCrosshair(xCrosshair);
        crosshairOverlay.addRangeCrosshair(yCrosshair);
        panel.addOverlay(crosshairOverlay);

        panel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {          
            @Override
            public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent event) {
                Rectangle2D dataArea = panel.getScreenDataArea();
                JFreeChart chart = event.getChart();
                XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
                ValueAxis xAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
                double x = xAxis.java2DToValue(event.getTrigger().getX(), dataArea, 
                        RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
                // make the crosshairs disappear if the mouse is out of range
                if (!xAxis.getRange().contains(x)) { 
                    x = Double.NaN;                  
                }
                double y = DatasetUtilities.findYValue(plot.getDataset(), 0, x);
                xCrosshair.setValue(x);
                yCrosshair.setValue(y);         
            }           
            @Override
            public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
                Rectangle2D dataArea = panel.getScreenDataArea();
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked on the graph");
                XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) xylineChart.getPlot();

                ValueAxis xAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
                double x = xAxis.java2DToValue(event.getTrigger().getX(), dataArea, 
                        RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
                // make the crosshairs disappear if the mouse is out of range
                if (!xAxis.getRange().contains(x)) { 
                    x = Double.NaN;                  
                }
                double y = DatasetUtilities.findYValue(plot.getDataset(), 0, x);

                System.out.println("Graph click: " + x + ":" + y);

                xCrosshair.setValue(x);
                yCrosshair.setValue(y);

                XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
                renderer.removeAnnotations();
                XYLineAnnotation mark = new XYLineAnnotation(x,0,x,250, new BasicStroke(), Color.BLACK);
                renderer.addAnnotation(mark);

                XYLineAnnotation low = new XYLineAnnotation(0.0f,dULD,400f,dULD, new BasicStroke(), Color.BLUE);
                renderer.addAnnotation(low);
                low.setToolTipText("low");
                XYLineAnnotation high = new XYLineAnnotation(0.0f,dLLD,400f,dLLD, new BasicStroke(), Color.MAGENTA);
                renderer.addAnnotation(high);
                high.setToolTipText("high");
                plot.setRenderer(renderer);
            }
        });

    }

    public void init() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE); 

        System.setSecurityManager(null);
        spc = new SimplePortComm();             
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
        DisplayPanel ds = new DisplayPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know  how `SimplePortComm` works,  but your `ActionListener` is replacing the `dataset` that was used to create the chart. It works the first time because the original dataset is the one that `xylineChart` is listening to; the chart doesn't know about the new `dataset`. You can tell the chart about the change by using `plot.setDataset(dataset);`

Your `ActionListener` is also blocking the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), so you might want to use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20SwingWorker).

Comment: Thanks a ton Catalina, I declared plot as global variable and called plot.setDataset(dataset); in ActionListener. Its working like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome. It sounds like the delay is not significant. You can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer when you're ready.